# Get all folder names in subfolders Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I have a below Folder Structure in Data Lake;

datasetname/fullload/year/month/day/hour/min/sec/data

[image]

I can't create Azure function or databrick. just simple adf activity

I want to get the latest folder names from all subfolders of my ParentFolder directory (datasetname/fullload) . I tried GetMetadata -> set variable then loop but still not working

[image]

[image]

I need to get the latest path of the folder in the blob storage

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by latest? Provide an example. How often do you get new folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you need the latest data and the folders are mostly numbers, you can find the greatest number in each sub folder to find the latest data.
- I have file data as shown in the below image:

[image]

- To find the greatest folder, I have used 2 pipelines. `pipeline1` is used to iterate and get child items until child items don't exist. `pipeline2` is to find the maximum number for the list of sub-folder names in a particular folder.
- The following is the pipeline JSON for pipeline1:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "get path",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set flag",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(variables('flag'),'true')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get sub folders",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "root",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "path": {
                                            "value": "@variables('path')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get sub folders",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greater(length(activity('Get sub folders').output.childItems),0)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifFalseActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Set variable1",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "flag",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "true",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "get latest",
                                        "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "pipeline": {
                                                "referenceName": "pipeline2",
                                                "type": "PipelineReference"
                                            },
                                            "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                            "parameters": {
                                                "array_to_find_max": {
                                                    "value": "@activity('Get sub folders').output.childItems",
                                                    "type": "Expression"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "append max to path",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "get latest",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "tp",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@{variables('path')}/@{activity('get latest').output.pipelineReturnValue.max_val}",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "update path",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "append max to path",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "path",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@variables('tp')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set flag",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set path",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "flag",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "false",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set path",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "path",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "data/f1/ff1",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "path": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "flag": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "values": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "max_val": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- The following is the pipeline JSON for pipeline2:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "make array of values",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.array_to_find_max",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "append each value",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "values",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@int(item().name)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "return max",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "make array of values",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "max_val",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@if(equals(length(string(max(variables('values')))),1),concat('0',string(max(variables('values')))),string(max(variables('values'))))"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "array_to_find_max": {
                "type": "array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "name": "2022",
                        "type": "Folder"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "2023",
                        "type": "Folder"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "values": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "max_val": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- The following is the dataset configuration that I used for get metadata activity. The initial value of path in my case is `data/f1/ff1` and its value would be updated (greatest folder name would be concatenated):

[image]

- When I run this pipeline, I get the desired results. After the until loop stops, the variable path has the required path i.e., the path to latest data:

[image]